# How to set Viewpager height from its Adapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Hi friends I'm working on an app which contains a ViewPager having heading and its description in each view. Initially only 3 lines of those description has to be shown but when clicked it will expand to full description.

I tried doing these but unfortunately couldn't achieve it. So, anyone can please help me with these.. Thanks in advance.

Xml

```
                    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/llDescriptionMap"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.explorelife.CustomViews.CustomViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/vpDescriptionMap"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                        android:id="@+id/indicatorDescriptionMap"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/vpDescriptionMap"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        app:radius="5dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

CustomViewPager

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager{
public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int height = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(h > height) height = h;
    }

    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

first your XML Must be like this..

```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

       >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

can you send your viewpager code first..